# A case for interface?

Tags: vb.net, interface

I have a class that should do different things with a form.

Because these "things" are specific to the form, I store the reference to the form like this:

```
Friend Class clsEdit

    Private m_Form As frmMain
```

And I pass it to the class like this:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef uForm As frmMain)

    m_Form = uForm

End Sub
```

Now when my class should do these "things", I do it like this:

```
MyEditClass.DoThings()
```

Internally it looks like this:

```
Public Sub DoThis()

    m_Form.SetHookPaused(True) 
    m_Form.StopCommonTimers()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    m_Form.DoSomethingThatOnlyThisFormCanDo()
End Sub
```

I would now like to be able to use clsEdit on a different form as well.
This other form also has the functions "DoThings" and "DoSomethingThatOnlyThisFormCanDo".

However, when I change the declaration of m_Form to this

```
Private m_Form As Form
```

... I can't do this anymore:

```
m_Form.DoThings()
```

... because "DoThings" is not a property / function of "Form".

And when I change it to this:

```
Private m_Form As frmOther
```

... I can't do that anymore:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef uForm As frmMain)

    m_Form = uForm

End Sub
```

Can anybody tell me how I could do this?

Comment: A form is already a class.  You can just add methods to the form rather than tuck it away in another class.  Not sure how Interfaces plays into your post.

Comment: Yes, if you have two different forms with the same methods and functions, then create an interface and use that instead.

Comment: Would you give me a kickstart on an interface for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your interface:

```
Public Interface IFormStuff
  Sub SetHookPaused(value As Boolean)
  Sub StopCommonTimers()
End Interface
```

Replace the form variable with the Interface variable in the class:

```
Public Class clsEdit
  Private m_Form As IFormStuff

  Public Sub New(f As IFormStuff)
    m_Form = f
  End Sub

  Public Sub DoThis()
    m_Form.SetHookPaused(True)
    m_Form.StopCommonTimers()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Implement the Interface in each form:

```
Public Class Form1
  Implements IFormStuff
```

and each form needs to implement those interface stubs:

```
Public Sub SetHookPaused(value As Boolean) Implements IFormStuff.SetHookPaused
  ' do something
End Sub

Public Sub StopCommonTimers() Implements IFormStuff.StopCommonTimers
  ' do something
End Sub
```

then you need to create the class at the form level:

```
Private myEdit As clsEdit = Nothing

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  myEdit = New clsEdit(Me)
End Sub
```

That's the gist of it.